# Stored Textures in C++ Projects

Tags: c++, assets, storage

I have executed the following command in order to store a texture (PNG) file in a C++ header file: `xxd -i Texture.png Texture.h`.

How would I go about loading this texture into OpenGL?

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
GLuint textureId;
glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
//glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

I realise that the function `glTexImage2D` should be used but am very unsure about which parameters to choose.

The specification describes the parameters as shown below.

```
void glTexImage2D(GLenum target, // GL_TEXTURE_2D
    GLint level, // 0
    GLint internalFormat, // GL_RGBA
    GLsizei width, // 2048
    GLsizei height, // 2048
    GLint border, // 0
    GLenum format, // What's this?
    GLenum type, // What's this?
    const GLvoid * data);
```

What are the `format` and `type` parameters for and what should they be set to in this case?

Comment: PNG is an image file format with headers, compression, etc.; `glTexImage2D` needs image data (array of color values), not an image file like PNG. You'll need a PNG loading function that can take a PNG file format and convert it into an array of colors. The format/type parameters for `glTexImage2D` will be the format of that array.

Comment: @amitp, ah, how would I go about pre-converting this into an array? I thought that the `xxd` command did that but have now found that it's just a hex dump of the file's data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you would load your images on-the-fly from a normal file then pass the decompressed pixels to OpenGL, but I'm also fond of embedding resources into the executable `:)`. For an extreme example, [see my PS2 game](https://bitbucket.org/glampert/ps2dev-tests/src/dfef4fc8fdeb352bfe598f3627092e58d2d01ea8/source/demos/dungeon_game/?at=master). The whole thing consists of a single 4 Megabytes executable, all assets built-in.

What I did, and you can also take the same approach if you want, is:

- Dump the binary contents of an image file (PNG, JPEG, etc) into a C-style array that you can compile with the rest of the application. You can write a simple tool to do that quite easily if you want. I use [`bin2c`](https://github.com/gwilymk/bin2c), which is pretty good and free.
- You still need to decompress your image data to raw RGB[A] pixels for OpenGL. A good public domain, single-file library that you can use is [STB Image](https://github.com/nothings/stb).
- Then just pass the address of the data array that was embedded with the help of `bin2c` to STB Image and the library will decompress the data and return a new pointer to the pixels that you can pass to OpenGL.

This is a viable setup for limited amounts of data, but very impractical for larger projects. Each time you change an image you have to do the whole cycle of `bin2c` -> recompile. It's fun as an experiment, but I can tell from own experience that near half way through the project I mentioned above I was regretting my choice of embedding everything, but in that specific case I had to do it due to external factors.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the answer I wanted as well as the one I needed!